# Impersonation – Attribute to Denote it’s Impersonation of Token

Tags: keycloak

We have impersonation roles for a number of admins -- it's working as expected.

A Client application, for audit purposes, would like to be informed when a token issued is via impersonation -- is there a way we can send an attribute/claim to the Client informing that the token is an Admin impersonating a user?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, Keycloak stores that information in user session notes. The information can be mapped via builtin mappers.

Follow these steps:

- Navigate to `Clients -> <your client> -> Mappers`
- Click `Add Builtin`
- Choose `Impersonator Username` and/or `Impersonator User ID` (depends on whether you want the username or id as a claim in the token)
- Click `Add selected`

That's it. Your tokens contain the information as shown below:

```json
{
  ...
  "sub": "9ab9bfd1-f95d-4aa1-a8b2-0d1fb06b365a",
  "preferred_username": "test",
  ...
  "impersonator": {
    "id": "2d2f4b4a-716c-4428-97cd-22fa731c0d9a",
    "username": "admin"
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: This works for OIDC but the builtin mapper does not exist for SAML clients.

Comment: @kensei62 Try to use a (non-builtin) Mapper of type `User Session Note` and use `IMPERSONATOR_ID` or `IMPERSONATOR_USERNAME` as the `User Session Note Attribute`.

Comment: Worked like a charm. @sventorben

Comment: Feature request: https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/issues/11610

Comment: This seems to have stopped working in Keycloak 19.0.3. Side note: the mapper now lives under the Client Scopes tab in the Client Details.

Comment: @kensei62 you are right, any solution to this issue?

Comment: @ScanQR We decided to implement a custom "staff login" function and drop impersonation.